# How do I Difference Panel Data in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I am wondering if there is any easy R commands or packages that will all allow me to easily add variables to data.frames which are the "difference" or change of over time of those variables.

If my data looked like this:

```
set.seed(1)
MyData <- data.frame(Day=0:9 %% 5+1, 
                 Price=rpois(10,10),
                 Good=rep(c("apples","oranges"), each=5))
MyData

   Day Price    Good
1    1     8  apples
2    2    10  apples
3    3     7  apples
4    4    11  apples
5    5    14  apples
6    1    12 oranges
7    2    11 oranges
8    3     9 oranges
9    4    14 oranges
10   5    11 oranges
```

Then after "first differencing" the price variable, my data would look like this.

```
   Day Price    Good P1d
1    1     8  apples  NA
2    2    10  apples   2
3    3     7  apples  -3
4    4    11  apples   4
5    5    14  apples   3
6    1    12 oranges  NA
7    2    11 oranges  -1
8    3     9 oranges  -2
9    4    14 oranges   5
10   5    11 oranges  -3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**ave**

```
transform(MyData, P1d = ave(Price, Good, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

**ave/gsubfn**

The last solution can be shorteneed slightly using `fn$` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)
transform(MyData, P1d = fn$ave(Price, Good, FUN = ~ c(NA, diff(x))))
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

MyData %>% 
  group_by(Good) %>% 
  mutate(P1d = Price - lag(Price)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(MyData)
dt[, P1d := c(NA, diff(Price)), by = Good]
```

### Update

dplyr now uses `%>%` instead of `%.%` .

Answer (score 2):

One can easily do it like this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

MyNewData <- 
 MyData %.%
 melt(id = c("Good", "Day")) %.%
 dcast(Day ~ Good) %.%
 mutate(apples  = apples - lag(apples),
     oranges = oranges - lag(oranges)) %.%
 melt(id = "Day", variable.name = "Good", value.name = "P1d") %.%
 merge(MyData) %.%
 arrange(Good, Day)
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the solution though I am not sure if I would say "easily". It seems to me rather complex. Especially given Stata would do the same command (gen P1d = Price-L1.Price) once the panel and time series identifiers are set.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to generate first differences for a panel. In order to have the differenced vector with the same length I used diff with a NA.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(price_diff = c(NA, diff(price)))%>%
ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  But it does not seem efficient in the least:

```
MyData$P1d <- c(NA, MyData$Price[-1]-MyData$Price[-nrow(MyData)])
MyData$P1d[c(F,MyData$Good[-1]!=MyData$Good[-nrow(MyData)])] <- NA

MyData

   Day Price    Good P1d
1    1     8  apples  NA
2    2    10  apples   2
3    3     7  apples  -3
4    4    11  apples   4
5    5    14  apples   3
6    1    12 oranges  NA
7    2    11 oranges  -1
8    3     9 oranges  -2
9    4    14 oranges   5
10   5    11 oranges  -3
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code following some dpylr tutorials online:
My goal was to add new column that is 5 year growth rate of R & D (variable xrd) of firms (identifer GVKEY). RandD2015 is raw data file.

By using the piping function (%>%) you can combine multiple calls in dplyr. Hope this is useful (my 1st code contribution in Stack Overflow)

```
library(dplyr)

RandDtest<- RandDec2015 %>% 
    group_by(GVKEY) %>%
    mutate(xrd5yr=xrd/lag(xrd,4)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`collapse::fdiff` is the function you are looking for:

```
library(collapse)
# This means compute difference of Price lagged once, iterated once, by Good, ordered by Day
settransform(MyData, P1d = fdiff(Price, 1, 1, Good, Day))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is **unbalanced**, examples such as [askesis_rea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61630922/19168959) and [G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610396/19168959) do not apply directly (Note: I did not test the other answers). But they apply after expanding the dataframe to a balanced panel with `NA` values.

## Example

In this example, individuals are not observed across all time periods.

Let's extend the example to the unbalanced case: (I remove day 2 for apples)

```r
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(Day=0:9 %% 5+1, 
                 Price=rpois(10,10),
                 Good=rep(c("apples","oranges"), each=5))
mydata <- mydata[!(mydata$Good=="apples" & mydata$Day==2), ]# removing apples in day 2
mydata
```

```
   Day Price    Good
1    1     8  apples
3    3     7  apples
4    4    11  apples
5    5    14  apples
6    1    12 oranges
7    2    11 oranges
8    3     9 oranges
9    4    14 oranges
10   5    11 oranges
```

Running [G. Grothendieck's `dplyr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610396/19168959) yields the wrong values:

```r
mydata %>% 
  group_by(Good) %>% 
  mutate(P1d = Price - lag(Price)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Indeed, for Day 3 and apples, the value should be 2 however it is -1.
This is because the difference between prices in Day 3 and 1 was computed rather than the difference between Day 3 and 2.

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
    Day Price Good      P1d
  <dbl> <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1     8 apples     NA
2     3     7 apples     -1
3     4    11 apples      4
4     5    14 apples      3
5     1    12 oranges    NA
6     2    11 oranges    -1
7     3     9 oranges    -2
8     4    14 oranges     5
9     5    11 oranges    -3
```

But if we expand first, and then apply first differencing, we get the right results:

```r
library(tidyr)
expanded <- mydata %>%  complete(nesting(Good), Day=full_seq(Day, 1))

expanded %>% 
  group_by(Good) %>% 
  mutate(P1d = Price - lag(Price)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Good      Day Price   P1d
   <chr>   <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 apples      1     8    NA
 2 apples      2    NA    NA
 3 apples      3     7    NA
 4 apples      4    11     4
 5 apples      5    14     3
 6 oranges     1    12    NA
 7 oranges     2    11    -1
 8 oranges     3     9    -2
 9 oranges     4    14     5
10 oranges     5    11    -3
```

**Edit**

In **some other scenario** of varying composition of individuals across time this method **might not be appropriate**.
One good tool is [fixest::d](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/feols.html) operator.
It can be used in fixest model formula or with data.table.

Example with `data.table`

1. Unbalanced

```r
library(data.table)
# creating the data
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(Day=0:9 %% 5+1, 
                 Price=rpois(10,10),
                 Good=rep(c("apples","oranges"), each=5))
mydata <- mydata[!(mydata$Good=="apples" & mydata$Day==2), ]# removing apples in day 2

mydata <- fixest::panel(as.data.table(mydata), panel.id=~Good + Day)
mydata[, P1D:=fixest::d(Price)] # Adding inplace first difference 

as.data.frame(fixest::unpanel(mydata)) # viewing
```

```
  Day Price    Good P1D
1   1     8  apples  NA
2   3     7  apples  NA
3   4    11  apples   4
4   5    14  apples   3
5   1    12 oranges  NA
6   2    11 oranges  -1
7   3     9 oranges  -2
8   4    14 oranges   5
9   5    11 oranges  -3
```

2. Balanced

```r
set.seed(1)
MyData <- data.frame(Day=0:9 %% 5+1, 
                 Price=rpois(10,10),
                 Good=rep(c("apples","oranges"), each=5))

MyData <- fixest::panel(as.data.table(MyData), panel.id=~Good + Day)
MyData[, P1D:=fixest::d(Price)]
as.data.frame(fixest::unpanel(MyData))
```

```
[1] TRUE
   Day Price    Good P1D
1    1     8  apples  NA
2    2    10  apples   2
3    3     7  apples  -3
4    4    11  apples   4
5    5    14  apples   3
6    1    12 oranges  NA
7    2    11 oranges  -1
8    3     9 oranges  -2
9    4    14 oranges   5
10   5    11 oranges  -3
```